# Django2: How to share 'request.user' with localhost:8000 and subdomain analysis.localhost:8000?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-hosts

i am building a blog using Django, and i have implemented an analysis tool that allows me to plot details about my visitors (country_origin, device, browser, ...).

**analysis.localhost:8000** is a subdomain of **localhost** , defined as a class based view with a custom Mixin **SuperuserAccessRequired**, that returns a **401 Unauthorized** if the user is not staff (i am using **django-hosts** to handle subdomains & this is my first time working with subdomains.).

My issue:

if i am logged in on **localhost:8000** and naviguate to **analysis.localhost:8000** i get the **401 response**.

```
You are seeing this as:  AnonymousUser # generated by print(You are seeing this as: ', request.user) from SuperuserAccessRequired
Unauthorized: /
[25/Sep/2019 13:14:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 401 89
```

my humble assumption says that **localhost:8000** and **x.localhost:8000** are not sharing certain variables.

How can i fix this issue, i have read django-hosts documentation like 5 times already and i can't seem to find what i am missing

my code :

project/root/settings.py

```
...
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']
ALLOWED_HOSTS += ['analysis.localhost', 'blog.localhost']

SITE_ID = 1

INSTALLED_APPS += [
    # Django Apps

    'blog',
    'analysis',
]

INSTALLED_APPS += [
    # Django Dependencies

    'sass_processor',
    'django_hosts',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django_hosts.middleware.HostsRequestMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'analysis.middleware.TrackVisitorMiddleware',
    'django_hosts.middleware.HostsResponseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'root.urls'
ROOT_HOSTCONF = 'root.hosts'
BLOG_URLCONF = 'blog.urls'
ANALYSIS_URLCONF = 'analysis.urls'
DEFAULT_HOST = 'www'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'analysis': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'analysis_db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

...
```

project/root/hosts.py

```
host_patterns = patterns('',
    host(r'localhost:8000', settings.ROOT_URLCONF, name='www'),
    host(r'analysis.localhost:8000', settings.ANALYSIS_URLCONF, name='analysis'),
    host(r'blog.localhost:8000', settings.BLOG_URLCONF, name='blog'),
)
```

Custom Mixin:

```
class SuperuserAccessRequired(AccessMixin):
    """Verify that the current user is staff."""
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('You are seeing this as: ', request.user)
        if not request.user.is_staff:
            return HttpResponse(status=401, content='You are not authorized to view this page.')
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**UPDATE**

If i remove the port number from **analysis.localhost** i get redirected to the Apache default page ... weird. (just dismiss this update i forgot about /etc/hosts, man i am losing it)

**UPDATE 2**

Digging deeper into the matter it looks like i have to rewrite my SessionMiddleware.

Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN for share cookie between subdomains.

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.localhost'
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sharesession'
```

See more info [SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain)

Comment: i tried this solution, and it prevented me from loging in. exactly what the django docs said.

Comment: i have moved everything under  django rest framework now i can log in there and  can see my analysis page by diving to api.localhost:8000/analysis/